# Android - Creating a Sync Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, synchronization

I know timers work by making the thread sleep for x amount of time but I was wondering if there is some sort of timer out there that doesn't run on a thread that's not the UI thread. I thought about using a loop that constantly compares the system time in milliseconds, but I want to use that as a last resort as it does not seem very efficient.

EDIT:

Stacktrace:

```
07-25 14:38:38.037  22108-22124/com.example.myapp E/ViewRootImpl﹕ com.example.myapp.Main : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6355)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:929)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChildFast(ViewGroup.java:4466)
        at android.view.View.invalidateViewProperty(View.java:11112)
        at android.view.View.setTranslationY(View.java:10472)
        at android.view.View.setY(View.java:10400)
        at com.example.myapp.Player.update(Player.java:29)
        at com.example.myapp.Main.update(Main.java:70)
        at com.example.myapp.Main.access$000(Main.java:15)
        at com.example.myapp.Main$1.run(Main.java:33)
        at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Relative Code:

```
if (!onGround){

        playerVisual.setY(playerVisual.getY() + this.gravity);

    }

    if (playerVisual.getY() >= this.main.getDevice().getHeight() - 10){
        this.onGround = true;
    }
    else {
        this.onGround = false;
    }
```

playerVisual is an ImageView if you were wondering.

Comment: Swing has a `Timer` class that runs events on Swing's main thread (which is not the one `main` runs on)

Comment: @immibis Is there a way to do this without using Swing?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. The reason there's no single simple way is: What happens if the thread is busy doing something else when a timer runs out?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you care about the timer thread not being the main thread?

Comment: @immibis I'm trying to create a timer that calls "update()" ever 50 milliseconds. It's for a game I'm developing. I was thinking I could use this method for game ticks.

Comment: @JBNizet The game I'm creating is for Android and whenever I use a regular timer and run updates from it, the app crashes saying views can only be accessed from the threads that created them.

Comment: OK. Then add the android tag on your question, replace "main thread" by "UI thread" (those two are quite different things), add the relevant code to your question, and the complete stack trace, so that we can help you understand what you're doing wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay I edited the original post.

Comment: @ReadySetPawn is `update()` a method of the `UI thread` ?

Comment: @user5001333 No, the update() method in the Main class gets called from the timer and that method calls the update() method in the Player class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution based on AsyncTask:

```
class AsyncTimer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    boolean alive = true;
    long startMS;
    long intervalMS;
    MainActivity activity;

    public AsyncTimer(long startMS, long intervalMS, MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.startMS = startMS;
        this.intervalMS = intervalMS;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(startMS);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (alive)
        {
            try
            {
                alive = activity.updateUI();
                Thread.sleep(intervalMS);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Using it in MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
        new AsyncTimer(0, 1000, this).execute();
    }

    public boolean updateUI()
    {
        Log.d("Timer", "tick");
...
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for updating the GUI from a scheduled task. Use Handler instead of Timer

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
 final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
{
public void run() 
{
    handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);  //1 second
    /*UPDATE GUI*/
    update();
}
};
myRunnable.run();
```

Comment: That works :) But it is there a way to make it repeat instead of just delay?

Comment: @ReadySetPawn    One way of doing it is to make a stack.

Answer (score -1):

You bascially want to block the current thread / wait on a condition - well
there are several options - the easiest one is to use [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) :

```
final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0); //not available at first
try
{
   semaphore.tryAcquire(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //block for 1 second since it isnt available
}
catch(InterruptedException ex)
{
   //do something sensible here
}
```

Another option is [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) :

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); //1 latch available
try
{
   latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //since currently one latch is available this will timeout
}
catch(InterruptedException ex)
{
   //do something sensible here
}
```

Granted : thats somewhat of an abuse of these classes, but it works flawlessy.
You could even use [Object.wait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,%20int)) but since an object can receive "spurious wakeups" you would have to deal with those - which isnt always as easy as it may appear to be at first.

Basically, you can use pretty much any mechanism which allows you to reliably "wait" on something - until your next time-slice is ready to be taken (hence : timeout on something) and continue in your loop.

In languages other than Java its possible to (reliably) suspend / pause the current thread for a fixed amount of time - thats even better but it breaks quite a few programming paradigms and it can be hard to understand; its best to not touch the thread itself unless you're really experienced and have a lot of knowledge about these things, blocking method invocations are almost always the best choice, even if that means writing a few extra lines of code.